# How to use struct as key in std::map

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2005, stdmap

I want to use a `std::map` whose key and value elements are structures.

I get the following error:
`error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const GUID`

I understand that I should overload `operator <` for that case, but the thing is I don't have access to the code of the structure I want to use (`GUID` structure in VC++).

Here's the code snippet:

```
//.h

#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<GUID,GUID> mapGUID;


//.cpp

GUID tempObj1, tempObj2;              
mapGUID.insert( pair<GUID,GUID>(tempObj1, tempObj2) );
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define the comparison operator as a freestanding function:

```
bool operator<(const GUID & Left, const GUID & Right)
{
    // comparison logic goes here
}
```

Or, since in general a < operator does not make much sense for GUIDs, you could instead provide a custom comparison functor as the third argument of the `std::map` template:

```
struct GUIDComparer
{
    bool operator()(const GUID & Left, const GUID & Right) const
    {
        // comparison logic goes here
    }
};

// ...

std::map<GUID, GUID, GUIDComparer> mapGUID;
```

Comment: when I write the way you said, I get errors, since `operator<` function should look like `bool operator<(GUID& left, GUID& right)`; Even after this I get compiler `error C2804: binary 'operator <' has too many parameters`. I don't understand why, cause this function is not placed inside my class containing maps?

Comment: @kobac -- I think that @Matteo meant to say `bool operator()(const std::pair<GUID, GUID> & Left, const std::pair<GUID, GUID> & Right)`

Comment: The correct answer is `bool operator()(const GUID &left, const GUID &right) const`

Comment: Ops, I got a bit messed up with the second one; sorry, now it should be fixed. :S

Comment: Still needs `operator()`. Please correct it so the people searching for the same problem would have a complete solution. Grazie Matteo.

Comment: @kobac: `operator()` is there, in `GUIDComparer`, what am I missing? Comunque prego, non c'è di che. :)

Answer (score 2):

Any type you use as a key has to provide a strict weak ordering. You can supply a comparator type as a third template argument, or you can overload `operator<` for your type.

Comment: upvoted for specifying _strict weak ordering_. This is important as otherwise a naive attempt at implementing our own `operator<` probably won't order strictly enough. Mine didn't, until I learned this term elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator < for GUIDS so you either have to provide the comparison operator or use a different key.

Answer (score 0):

May be using class inherited from GUID in which you implement operator < would be a workaround for you?